# Where do IP Address & Filter recorded in Bigquery Export Scheme?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I have a `view` and it has several filters such as excluding `IP Address` and the following screenshot:

[image]

Where do i find `Application?` field in my Google Analytic Bigquery?
Which of [these](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719) column record `IP Address` and `Application?` field?

Thanks in advance!

Update: add relevant image
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IP Address` isn't available in BigQuery due to privacy issues.

However, although `Application?` isn't directly available in BigQuery either, note that it can be reproduced based on `hits.dataSource`. Since `hits.dataSource` has `web` or `app` as possible values, you can easily use this field to reproduce `Application?` (whose possible values seems to be `YES` or `NO` according to [this](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6014418?hl=en)) with a `CASE WHEN` clause:

```
CASE
    WHEN hits.dataSource = 'app' THEN 'YES'
    ELSE 'NO'
  END AS Application
```